# Video players that display audio waveforms

Tags: video, media-player

Are there any programs that can play video and display the audio track as a waveform? I need one for either OSX, Linux, or Windows.

Comment: It has to be just a player? I've only seen NLE's that do this.

Comment: Do you mean like an oscilloscope playback, or a non-linear video editor look?

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40627/is-there-an-audio-player-with-waveform-seekbar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found one that does what I was looking for. It's not just a video player but a subtitle program called [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/).

[image: Aegisub interface screenshot (waveform view)]

[image: Aegisub interface screenshot (spectrum view)]

As opposed to suggested software in other answers, you can se the waveform of the entire video (to be exact: of one of its tracks) and use it - for example - for navigating through the video.

Comment: This is an excellent use of this tool, thanks for sharing your solution! You can also use most video editors, for example Kdenlive or Shotcut but their audio waveform display might be too small and playback might have too low performance. On the other hand they allow for easier navigation (I haven't found how to use the audio waveform in aegisub to change the playback moment/time)

Comment: Great tool! It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 5):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) supports all platforms.

It has an Oscilloscope function,
[image: preview of VLC's oscilloscope visualization]

and a Spectrum function.
[image: preview of VLC's spectrum visualization]

Comment: Nothing happens when i click spectrum or oscilloscope when playing a video... what could i be missing?

Comment: @Draken check the forums! https://forum.videolan.org/index.php

Comment: it shows a window of waveform, not the full audio clip.

Answer (score 2):

[WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com) can show an oscilloscope, or spectrum analyzer while playing video. You may need to use the Big Bento skin (comes with WinAmp).